# Using movefile command in matlab to move files to a folder created through string operations

Tags: matlab

The following works fine with matlab.

```
mkdir NewFolder; 
movefile *.csv NewFolder;
```

Every csv files are moved on to the NewFolder succesfully.

I want to have the Newly created folders the date when it was created so i used the following command.

```
foldername = ['Results_'  num2str(num(1))  '_'  num2str(num(2)) '_'num2str(num(3))];
```

and

```
mkdir(foldername)
```

created the folder Results_2017_9_15.

**Now how will I use `movefile` command to move all csv files to this New folder?**

I tried the following and some variants

```
movefile *.csv foldername
```

but it was not working.

Comment: You correctly used function syntax for `mkdir(foldername)` (required since you want the *value* of the variable and not the literal representation passed to `mkdir`); why did you abandon it for the `movefile` call?

Comment: And a suggestion: adding `'%02d'` as a second argument to `num2str` will put a leading `0` on the single digit months and days, and this will effect proper sorting of the directory listings.

Comment: @TroyHaskin did you mean like movefile(*.csv,foldername), I tried it but was not working

Comment: What about `movefile('*.csv',foldername)`?

Comment: @TroyHaskin That worked.. thank you friend.. :)

Comment: See: [Command vs. Function Syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution from [TroyHaskin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121310/troyhaskin) comments.

Posting it here in case someone may find it useful.

`movefile('*.csv',foldername)` will do the work.